# php footer links

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hyperlink

how do i get the headers for my footer to become  a link ? currently i have this code :

```
                    <div id="footer">
                     <div id="foot">
                     <ul class="clearfix">
                  <li>Stores 
                     <ul>
            <li><a href="/stores/speedway">Speedway</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stores/ina">Ina</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stores/grant">Grant</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stores/phoenix">Phoenix</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stores/mesa">Mesa</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stores/flagstaff">Flagstaff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/stores/sports">Sports Exchange</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want the header STORES to become a link or click-able and go to the main page for stores how do i do that without changing the color which is white.
how do i do that.

Comment: You should define correct CSS styles for `li` and `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use inline styles to override the coloring.

```
<a href="/stores/" style="text-decoration:none;color:white">Stores</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or JavaScript in the onclick event to do the link behavior.

```
<li id="#stores" onclick="location.href='/stores/';">Stores
...
```

Then you set the style in your stylesheet for the stores id:

```
#stores {
   color: white;
   ...
}
```